# Difference between macOS login root and Darwin Terminal root

Tags: user-account, accounts, root

The recent major security flaw in macOS 11.13.[1,2] has turned the usual advice of not enabling the `root` account on its head. But it has left me a bit confused about exactly what `root` account is being discussed.

The Darwin shell has a `root` account listed, and has many files and directories listed as owned by `root`, but macOS has no login account enabled for `root`.

What's the difference between the `root` account listed as an existing owner for files in the Terminal, and the (disabled) `root` login account?

Answer (score 4):

The *root* user (UID 0) exists in every Unix or Unix-like operating system. Every process of a Unix operating systems must run as a valid user/UID, independently of system processes, daemons, services or user-initiated applications. Every basic system-process runs under UID 0 (root), and every system-relevant file is owned by that user. For reasons of security, some processes are running as different "users" with lesser privileges than the superuser *root*. Such users are there for the solely purpose to start services, such as a webserver, a database, the window server and so on. This means, not every user configured on Unix (or macOS) is a "real" user. In fact, most of those system-users can not log-in interactively.

For example a webserver (nginx, apache, ...) will be started by a script running under UID 0 (=*root*). The webserver-process afterwards drops the privileges to a specific UID (in this case, it could be the user *www*). *www* is not a real user and cannot be used to log in to the system interactively.
There are two ways to "deactivate" a (system) user:

- set the user shell to /bin/false (or any non valid-shell)
- disable the users's password, setting it to an invalid, empty or specific value.

On macOS AFAIK a non-valid user has an empty password and a specific property set on the local OpenDirectory server.

Usually, for a request like "is this a valid user" the OpenDirectory service in macOS does a simple check on the requested user and returns true (user can log in) or false (user cannot log in).
It seems, Apples bug was not to *check* user's validity but to *set* it to enabled. On already enabled accounts this had no effect, but disabled accounts  became valid, enabled accounts. And since a disabled user has no password, an empty password was accepted as a valid option to log in as superuser/*root*.

Comment: What does it mean, in this context, that `dscl . list /Users UserShell` gives `root /bin/bash` (though I have no interactive login for that set up)?

Comment: @orome This means that the `root` user, if it would be enabled, would get `/bin/bash` as shell. Use `sudo /usr/bin/dscl . -create /Users/root UserShell /usr/bin/false` to change it for extra security.

Comment: @patrix: And doing that just changes the shell that `rout` would get *if* it were enabled (but doesn't enable it), correct?

Comment: @orome What else would you expect to be impacted here?

Comment: @patrix: What I asked about parenthetically. Is the answer secret?

Comment: @Orome it sets the shell, it doesn‘t enable login. And with the shell set to /usr/bin/false a login is not possible even if enabled as such.

Comment: @patrix: Interesting: since the security patch — to 10.13.1 (17B1003) — `root` is changed to `/bin/sh` (rather than what it was: `/bin/bash`). [Thoughts on what that accomplishes? Would it still make sense to set it to `/usr/bin/false`?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/307542/4395)

Answer (score 3):

File ownership does not require that a user can login. Files that run the operating system are typically owned by root and are placed by an installation process that requires some form of authentication. Also, the operating system uses other users that run processes beside root. These user usually have their shell set to `/bin/false` ,cannot login, and may produce files owned by themselves.

To list users on your system and their shell:

```
dscl . list /Users UserShell
```

To find files on your system not owned by root or you:

```
sudo find -x / ! \( -user root -o -user "$(id -un)" \) -exec ls -ld {} +
```

Comment: The first command lists (aside from a bunch of `/usr/bin/false` users): `_mbsetupuser  /bin/bash`,  `_uucp /usr/sbin/uucico`, `root  /bin/bash`, and `Rax /bin/bash`.