# Secure setting for shell for unused root account

Tags: security, root

The security patch to Apple's root login security flaw — to 10.13.1 (17B1003) — has changed the shell setting reported by

```
dscl . list /Users UserShell
```

for `root` to `/bin/sh` (from `/bin/bash`). What does this accomplish? It's been suggested that for extra security I should set the shell for `root` to to `/usr/bin/false`. Does it still make sense to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Basically `bash` and `sh` are two different shells, have a look [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/141928/what-is-difference-between-bin-sh-and-bin-bash). Maybe an Apple employee liked `sh` more than `bash` and changed? :-)

[This question and answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/272611/root-shell-mistakenly-changed-how-can-i-change-it-back-to-a-valid-shell) discuss login shells in some details. But the short answer is yes, it **always** makes sense to put the login shell for root to something non-existing.

(Technically it is not **always**, but in those cases you hopefully don't have to ask that question :-) )

Comment: So the change from `bash` to `sh` is of little consequence, right? (Importantly, unlikely to be a crucial component of the security fix.)

Comment: @orome Indeed, the differences between `sh` and `bash` are mostly subjective (in that it is a matter of taste), if there was a bug in either `sh` or `bash` that would be more than huge.

Comment: On macOS, `bash` and `sh` are compiled from the same source code but `sh` is configured differently than `bash`.

Comment: [I'm getting conflicting advice.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/408246/9297)

Comment: @orome If you ever need to use it, just change it by using `sudo`. If you ever need to log into root you can assume, safely, that you are doing something the wrong way. Sometimes it might be the faster way, but definitely not the right way.